# How to export qcow2 KVM image?

Tags: xubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu, qcow2

I have set up a new QEMU virtual machine through KVM on a Ubuntu 14.10 linux installation.

Everything is working smoothly. The problem is when I try to export the qcow2 vm image to another PC, to migrate the vm.

The qcow2 image is 4GB though the real virtual drive is 100GB.

When I try to move the qcow2 image to an external USB drive it automatically increases its size to 100GB. I tried to convert the qcow2 to a raw image, then zip it and move it to the external drive. It works but then when I import the raw image on the second PC and I turn the VM on, I get a message error saying "boot device cannot be found" - even though the vm is working well on the first PC.

Why is this happening? Is there an easy way to export the qcow2 image to make it easy importing the VM on another PC?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution using tar which will keep the sparse file size!

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: please share your solution